# About the passive ability from Lux

Tags: league-of-legends

Okay, so Lux' passive marks an enemy everytime you hit him with a spell, so you have like 6 seconds to hit him with your AA to "ignite" it, which means you will deal some more magical damage.

Now I played quite some games with Lux and also read some Guides, but I still didn't figure these 2 things out ( because when I engage I just bring down my combo without looking for details ^^ )

1. Does her passive get "ignited" only by AA or also by her other spells?
2. Does her Ulti also mark the enemy ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Lux's passive, Illumination, is ignited both by her auto-attacks and her ultimate, Finales Funkeln.
2. Yes, Finales Funkeln both ignites any present Illumination debuff on the enemy and applies a new Illumination debuff after resolution.

Comment: Well I usually go for Q -> E ( dont explode ) -> R -> E ( explode ) -> AA - does the explosion from E ignites the new debuff from the R ?

Comment: Again, the only spell that ignites Illumination is her R. You would need an auto-attack between R and E's detonation to fully utilize Illumination in your hypothetical.

Comment: Okay, so best case would be Q(stun&debuff) -> E ( just lies there ) -> R ( Ignite&debuff ) -> AA ( ignite ) -> E ( explode&debuff) -> AA ( ignite ) ? What would be your suggestion to bring down a combo ( if you try to burst down one enemy )

Comment: I do not play Lux myself, but I've most often seen E->AA in midflight->Q in midflight->E detonation->AA lands->Q lands->R->AA from higher-level Lux players, such as Riot Janook.

Comment: Haha okay, well that seems quite sophisticated compared to my way of bursting the enemy! Well anyways, thanks four your help, you cleared some things up for me!

Comment: Glad to help. :)